# I need to build a wpf application with some animations, whats the best and fastet way to start with?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I need to build a wpf application with some animations, what do you recommend me to use (sample applications, books tutorials) that can benefit me very fast taking into consideration I have a 6 years experience in DotNet apps.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've just started WPF myself, and I can highly recommend Adam Nathan's book:  'WPF Unleashed'. [http://www.amazon.com/Windows-Presentation-Foundation-Unleashed-WPF/dp/0672328917](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0672328917) .  It has  a friendly style with lots of colour illustrations.  It also seeks to teach by example.
I would also suggest you download Vertigo's Family.Show and 'dig around under the bonnet'.  This is a teaching application that uses every trick in the WPF book it can:  styles, templates and the suchlike.  Get it from http://www.vertigo.com/familyshow.aspx